# How can I serve all resources under HTTPS instead of HTTP without changing their URLs in the HTML code

Tags: html, htaccess, apache, https, nginx

I know that by using an *.htaccess* file I can redirect everyone to `https://`. However, my SSL certificate complains if all the content isn't served under HTTPS.

Is there a way to convert all the resources to be served under HTTPS without changing all the `http://` URLs to `https://` in the HTML code?

EXAMPLE: If I type in `http://domain.com` it will go to `https://domain.com`. However, the images are not using HTTPS which causes issues. Is there a way to make ALL the resources use HTTPS?

I have this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

However, my EV certificate will vanish because of unsecured content. So I need all the images to also be served under HTTPS.

Comment: Your question is a bit fuzzy and I am not entirely sure I understand what your are asking. I am reading that you want to modify resources and I read that as HTML files and other similar resources to include other file types such as PDF etc to result in SSL and HTTPS. I am working on that assumption. SSL over HTTPS is a communications encryption protocol that has nothing to do with the source files of a website. Using the .htaccess file to force the use of HTTPS as a protocol is the correct procedure. There is no modifying of files that results in SSL or HTTPS outside of using .htaccess or the

Comment: What code are you using in .htaccess to do the redirect? Is it content-type specific?

Comment: It just does the URL. Is there a way to also do all the content URLs?

Comment: Could you post your redirect code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to **drop the 'http:' prefix** from all image (and any other) links on your site. When you do so, your browser will default to whatever protocol the page loads with. For example this is best:

```
<a href="//www.example.com/">
```

And this is not:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/">
```

The top example is perfectly valid markup and you will load all your resources over an HTTPS connection with the rewrite you already use. Start using it for all links as it works with both HTTP and HTTPS, so you won't ever have this issue again if you enable or disable SSL.

The only consideration is if you are using a CDN or other third-party hosted content on your site. If you are, the above advice will only work if they make their resources available over HTTPS also.

Once you do this, your EV (Extended validation) certificate will work as you are expecting and you should see all resources on the page load over a secure connection.

Comment: Cool. I did not know you could do that

Answer (score 2):

As a quick fix, you can [ask the web browser to rewrite all your HTTP URLs as HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests) by sending the `Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests;` header or `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">` meta tag with every page.

This is not meant to be used as a permanent solution, but as as a transition tool until you can get all your URLs converted to `https`.