# How can I make a browser trust my SSL certificate when I request resources from an external server?

Tags: https, security-certificate

I have installed an SSL certificate on one of my domains and it works perfectly, but on some pages I include a Google Font, which causes my certificate icon to change in:

[image]

instead of:

[image]

The reason, according to Google Chrome (translated with Google Translate):

> Your connection to xxxxxx is encrypted with 128-bit encryption. This page includes other resources which are not secure. These resources can be viewed by others while in transit and can be modified to fit.

So how can I make the browser 'trust' my SSL certificate, even though I request an external resource from Google Fonts?

And also, does it matter that I use links like these:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='et-shortcodes-css-css'  href='https://xxxxxx/wp-content/themes/Divi/epanel/shortcodes/css/shortcodes.css?ver=3.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

instead of

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='et-shortcodes-css-css'  href='wp-content/themes/Divi/epanel/shortcodes/css/shortcodes.css?ver=3.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I'll try it out when I have time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I serve all resources under HTTPS instead of HTTP without changing their URLs in the HTML code](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61750/how-can-i-serve-all-resources-under-https-instead-of-http-without-changing-their)

Comment: @TomBrossman No, this is a different question.

Comment: Don't forget to approve an answer.

Comment: In that case, people usually pick one and that is fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `https` to fetch resources not located on your server. If it does not work (or if `https` is not supported), try to move the Google font file (css and woff) on your website server rather than fetching them from Google Font itself (ditto for other external resources).

Regarding explicitly using `https` for resources located on your server, it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `href="/wp-content/themes/Divi/epanel/shortcodes/css/shortcodes.css" in your HTML code.

Then you should make sure that you use `https://` form URLs in your CSS file for the URLs to any external resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can put `//` in front of your hrefs, that way it will use the same protocol as the requesting page.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it didn't work, now I notice it actually does and it was an error from my side. Sorry for the downvote, because I don't seem to be able to upvote it again (error: You last voted on this answer Aug 21 at 12:39. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited.)

Answer (score -1):

To improve user's security, **Google** has [**recently announced**](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.in/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html) that it has quit support for **SHA-1 (128 bit)** signature algorithm, that means it will not consider site that is encrypted with SHA-1.

To solve this error you need to contact your Certificate authority and ask for reissue your SSL certificate with **SHA-2 (> 256 bit)** encryption algorithm.

SHA-2 algorithm is compatible with compatible with updated version of Google Chrome.

After installing SSL with **SHA-2** encryption algorithm you can see your Website with Green address bar.

Comment: -1, this isn't an answer to my question. Consider adding this as a comment though.